# Applying the restrictions on the schema source for an RTF field

Tags: xslt, tridion

I want to apply some extra filtering xslt in one Tridion Schema.

I have a field with the name "image". It is an RTF, it has been configured to allow images and hyperlink by selecting it under edit formatting features.

The idea behind it is to insert and Image in RTF and make it as an RTF field.

sample Valid source:

```
1.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
2.<a title="Internal link" href="tcm:202-9720"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
```

As the RTF is allows Hyperlink and Image there may be chance that user may enter them in different formats.
Invalid:

```
1.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"></a>
  <img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/>

2.<img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/>
 <a title="google site" href="http://google.com"></a>

3.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
  <a title="Internal link" href="tcm:202-9720"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
```

Rules:

```
1.Only one Image should be allowed and it should be hyperlink.
2.There should be one <img> tag wrapped by one <a> tag.
3. Multiple images are not allowed.
```

I know that this could be done using Event system. But Still I thought of implementing by applying XSLT filtering.

XSLT filtering Source:

```
<xsd:element name="image" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tcmi:XHTML">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
                    <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">2</tcm:Size>
                    <tcm:FilterXSLT xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                        <stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                            <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
                            <template match="/ | node() | @*">
                                <copy>
                                    <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
                                </copy>
                            </template>
                            <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
                                <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
                            </template>
                            <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
                                <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
                                <text> </text>
                            </template>
                            <template name="FormattingFeatures">
                                <FormattingFeatures xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.2/FormatArea" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                                    <Doctype>Transitional</Doctype>
                                    <AccessibilityLevel>0</AccessibilityLevel>
                                    <DisallowedActions>
                                        <Bold></Bold>
                                        <Italic></Italic>
                                        <Underline></Underline>
                                        <Strikethrough></Strikethrough>
                                        <Subscript></Subscript>
                                        <Superscript></Superscript>
                                        <AlignLeft></AlignLeft>
                                        <Center></Center>
                                        <AlignRight></AlignRight>
                                        <Bullets></Bullets>
                                        <Numbering></Numbering>
                                        <IndentDecrease></IndentDecrease>
                                        <IndentIncrease></IndentIncrease>
                                        <Font></Font>
                                        <Background></Background>
                                        <InsertCharacter></InsertCharacter>
                                        <Anchor></Anchor>
                                        <Table></Table>
                                        <TableWidth></TableWidth>
                                        <TableHeight></TableHeight>
                                        <TableCellSpacing></TableCellSpacing>
                                        <TableCellPadding></TableCellPadding>
                                        <TableHAlign></TableHAlign>
                                        <TableBorderSize></TableBorderSize>
                                        <TableBorderStyle></TableBorderStyle>
                                        <TableBorderColor></TableBorderColor>
                                        <TableBackground></TableBackground>
                                        <TableCellWidth></TableCellWidth>
                                        <TableCellHeight></TableCellHeight>
                                        <TableCellHAlign></TableCellHAlign>
                                        <TableCellVAlign></TableCellVAlign>
                                        <TableCellBackground></TableCellBackground>
                                        <HLine></HLine>
                                        <SectionType></SectionType>
                                        <H1></H1>
                                        <H2></H2>
                                        <H3></H3>
                                        <H4></H4>
                                        <H5></H5>
                                        <H6></H6>
                                        <Style></Style>
                                        <Language></Language>
                                        <Abbreviation></Abbreviation>
                                        <CurrentElement></CurrentElement>
                                    </DisallowedActions>
                                    <DisallowedStyles></DisallowedStyles>
                                </FormattingFeatures>
                            </template>
                        </stylesheet>
                    </tcm:FilterXSLT>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
```

I want to know that whether I can do it by writing some xslt code in tcm:FilterXSLT of the schema source.

Can any one help how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider a component links as an alternative approach since it offers control over valid schema and the markup that wrap the link (via template code). What should the `<a>` point to? You could manage that hyperlink (and other metadata) in another component, in the multimedia metadata, or a possibly with a custom link type GUI extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. It does the following:

- Looks for the first 'a' element in your rich text
- if there is an 'img' element inside it, it keeps it as is
- if there is not, it looks for the first img element anywhere else in the rich text and moves it into the a element
- all other elements are removed

Tested on 2011 sp1. And I have to say, it was fun playing with xslt again, it's been too long :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></xsl:output>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a[1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//a">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(img)">
              <xsl:copy-of select="//img"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have added it under XSLT filtering, but its not working as expected. I just wanted to know, how to handle multiple Image fields and if there is no a tag, how it behaves. Because I tried them, its not working fine.

Comment: You should see this as an example implementation, with the business rules that I indicated. If you have to implement different business rules, you could at least use this as a starting point. A little XSLT knowledge goes a long way here..